# Cypress error Cypress.moment.duration (moment is not defined)

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress and upgraded to version to v8.3.1 and a new error keeps showing up.

```
Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined

Because this error occurred during a after all hook we are skipping all of the remaining tests.
```

Location: `node_modules/@cypress/code-coverage/support.jsat line210`

```js
  cy.task('coverageReport', null, {
    timeout: Cypress.moment.duration(3, 'minutes').asMilliseconds(),
                           ^
    log: false
  })
```

It says that `duration` cannot be found since `Cypress.moment` doesn't exist.

I checked the changelog and they removed it:

```
Cypress.moment() has been removed. Please migrate to a different datetime formatter. See our recipe for example replacements. Addresses #8714.
```

But since I'm not directly using it, it's in the code coverage included in `Cypress`, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you've obtained an old version of @cypress/code-coverage.

Perhaps you upgraded Cypress and not the code-coverage package?

**@cypress/code-coverage@3.2.0 - support.js**

```js
after(function generateReport() {
  // when all tests finish, lets generate the coverage report
  cy.task('coverageReport', {
    timeout: Cypress.moment.duration(3, 'minutes').asMilliseconds()
  })
})
```

**@cypress/code-coverage@3.9.10 - support.js**

```js
after(function generateReport() {
  ...
  cy.task('coverageReport', null, {
    timeout: dayjs.duration(3, 'minutes').asMilliseconds(),
    log: false
  }).then((coverageReportFolder) => {
  ...
})
```

`npm update @cypress/code-coverage` should fix it